# Why are my tableVeiws Rows so Jumpy while scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Below is the code of my tableView controller which takes an image from a UIImage array resizes it to aspect ratio and displays it on screen. While I scroll the images are very choppy? Is there anyway to reduce the choppiness?

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var images = imagePost.defaultimages //An array of a class containing images
var indexPathPass = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.backgroundColor =  colors.backgroundColor
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: self.indexPathPass, at: .top, animated: false)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

        cell.cellImageView.image = self.images[indexPath.row].image
    cell.cellImageView.image = cell.cellImageView.image?.resizeImageWith()

    cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 20, blue: 1, alpha: 0.99)
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    return cell
        }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 100
 }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do computation heavy code in your hot  path? Additionally, your not saving the resized image back into the `self.image` so you are repeating this operation? Would it not be better to perform, in batches, the resize in an `NSOperation` so its is only done in your cellForRowAtIndexPth if it hasn't been resized yet?

Comment: @Freddy I just saved the resized images back into the array and it worked really well the jumpiness is gone, thank you so much.

Comment: @Freddy how would I implement this as an NSOperation

Comment: @user372382 go to interface builder and set tableview bounces No

Comment: There's no reason to implement the `estimatedHeightForRowAt` method if it is just going to return the same value for every row. Setting the `estimatedRowHeight` property in `viewDidLoad` as you are is enough in this case.

Comment: @user372382 Create an `NSOperationQueue` and an `NSOperation`. During your initialization code fire off a batch that resizes the images and a flag to  identify they have been loaded. Until the batch is done, show a place holder image. Once loaded redraw the table and use the flag to identify the images in your array has the resized images.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the difference in your **estimatedRowHeight** and the actualRowHeight, the more is the difference the more it will jump while scrolling.

Comment: All of the cells are being resized according to the aspect ratio of the photo it is inevitable that the estimated row height will differ from the actual row height. How do I estimate the estimated row height closer to the actual row height if the actual row height is constantly changing.

Comment: the default size of a row is 45, try putting your estimatedRowHeight down to this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1.**

- If possible, try to implement 'heightForItem at indexPath' method. And return calculated height

**Solution 2.**

- You can implement height caching mechanism. Like below code.

  class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

  ```
  var images = imagePost.defaultimages //An array of a class containing images
  var indexPathPass = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

  fileprivate var cachedHeight = [IndexPath: CGFloat]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
      tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
      tableView.backgroundColor =  colors.backgroundColor
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: self.indexPathPass, at: .top, animated: false)
      }
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

      // Configure the cell...

      cell.cellImageView.image = self.images[indexPath.row].image
      cell.cellImageView.image = cell.cellImageView.image?.resizeImageWith()

      cell.backgroundColor =  UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 20, blue: 1, alpha: 0.99)
      cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
      return cell
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return cachedHeight[indexPath] ?? 100
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      cachedHeight[indexPath] = cell.frame.height
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: heightForRowAt for a particular indexpath is called before willDisplayCell... How is this solution going to work?